# Show plots with R in jupyter: windows() function crashing

Tags: r, jupyter

I use R in jupyter with IRkernel. I want to get a resizable window with the plots since jupyter shows plots in a  fixed size.

With RStudio, I used the `windows()` function before plotting. However, with jupyter a window opens but it is not responding (I have to kill it in task manager).

Is there a workaround or another function to use?

Comment: You can use this: `options(repr.plot.width = 1, repr.plot.height = 0.75)
`

Comment: It gives me the `invalid graphics state` error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution is to use `repr.plot.width`, `repr.plot.height` and `repr.plot.res`.
However, I needed to use a lot bigger values (5/10/15) to avoid the `invalid graphics state` error.

For example,
`options(repr.plot.width=10, repr.plot.height=10, repr.plot.res=500)`